# Regex with optional part doesn't create backreference

Tags: c#, .net, regex, capturing-group

I want to match an optional tag at the end of a line of text.

Example input text:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog {tag}
```

I want to match the part in curly-braces and create a back-reference to it.

My regex looks like this:

```
^.*(\{\w+\})?
```

(somewhat simplified, I'm also matching parts before the tag):

It matches the lines ok (with and without the tag) but doesn't create a back-reference to the tag.

If I remove the '?' character, so regex is:

```
^.*(\{\w+\})
```

It creates a back-reference to the tag but then doesn't match lines without the tag.

I understood from http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html that the optional operator wouldn't affect the backreference:

> Round brackets group the regex between them. They capture the text matched by the regex inside them that can be reused in a backreference, and they allow you to apply regex operators to the entire grouped regex.

but must've misunderstood something.

How do I make the tag part optional and create a back-reference when it exists?

Comment: Using C#/.NET with System.Text.RegularExpressions classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a backreference problem, the problem is that the regular expression was satisfied by just reading in the text that matched `.*`.  It didn't feel compelled to continue reading to read the optional end-tag.  The simplest solution if you're truly reading to the end of the line is to append a `$` (dollar sign) to force the regular expression to match the whole line.

**edit**

BTW, I didn't take your reg-ex literally since you said it matches other stuff, but just to be clear `.*` will consume the whole line.  You'd need something like `[^{]*` to prevent the tag from getting swallowed.  I'm guessing that's not a problem for you.

Comment: @Gumbo, @padriagf said in his question that the regular expression in question was more complicated, so it may or may not consume the tag.  I tried to make it clear that he needs to check for that.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what others have explained, you might want to make the `.*` "lazy":

```
^.*?(\{\w+\})?
```

Comment: Or "not greedy" is another term for `*?` - Which always tries to find the shortest possible match ( as opposed to the longest possible match )

Comment: This won't actually work, though—see my answer.  The lazy quantifier will match nothing.  You can [try it for yourself](http://www.rubular.com/r/hjknUHyFQ7).

Answer (score 1):

As David Gladfelter said, the actual problem is that when you make it optional, it doesn't match<s>; however, his proposed fix won't work</s>.  **Edit 1:** You'll need to use what he put in his edit (which got written as I was writing this).  The problem is that quantifiers (`*`, `+`, `?`, `{n,m}`) are *greedy*: they always match as much as they possibly can.  Thus, when you write `^.*(\{\w+\})?`, the `.*` will always match the whole line, because an empty match satisfies the optional group.  Also note that although `?` is greedy, the first greediness (of `.*`) takes precedence.  If you're only allowed to have curly brackets around that optional group, then you can solve your problem by saying so explicitly: `^[^\{]*(\{\w+\})?`.  This way, the first chunk will match everything up to the first curly bracket, and then (since `?` is greedy) match the curly-bracketed word if it can.

Often, another way to solve this is to make the quantifiers *lazy* (or non-greedy, minimal, etc.) by appending a `?`: `*?`, `+?`, `??`, and `{n,m}?`.  However, this won't help you here: instead, if you do `^.*?(\{\w+\})?`, the lazy `.*?` will try to match zero characters, succeed, and then the optional group won't match.  Still, though it won't work here, it's a useful tool in your toolbox.  **Edit 1:**  Also, note that these aren't available in all regex engines, although they are available in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys. I used a combination of answers, the not-greedy modifier and the end-of-line match, which seems to do the trick, so regex is now:

```
^.*?(\{\w+\})?$
```

I didn't want to use [^{]* for the first part of the match, as non-tag curly brackets may appear here, but tags will always be at the end of the line.

Thanks for the answers, they were all helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only interested in the tag, and doesn't care about the rest of the string, then you'd make your life much easier by just matching the tag with this regex ([see it on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/U41SEsTrDY)):

```
\{(\w+)\}$
```

That is, you're trying to match some `{word}` at the end of the string. If it's not there, then too bad, there's no match. There is no need for a `?` modifier or a reluctant `.*` and all that stuff.

In C#, you may even want to use `RegexOptions.RightToLeft`, since you're trying to match a suffix anyway, so perhaps something like this:

```
string[] lines = {
  "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog",
  "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog {tag}",
  "The quick brown fox jumps over the {lazy} dog",
  "The quick brown fox jumps over the {lazy} {dog}",
};

Regex r = new Regex(@"\{(\w+)\}$", RegexOptions.RightToLeft);

foreach (string line in lines) {
  Console.WriteLine("[" + r.Match(line).Groups[1] + "]");
}
```

This prints ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/Das1Z)):

```
[]
[tag]
[]
[dog]
```